# Why do we use the diagonal for diagonal approximations ? 

Tags: group-cohomology, homological-algebra

First recall how the cup product is defined for the cohomology of a group $G$:

Fix a projective resolution $P \to \mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$. Then $P \otimes P \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ is a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G \otimes \mathbb{Z}G=\mathbb{Z}[G \times G]$. Since the diagonal 
$$D: G \to G \times G,\;g \mapsto (g,g)$$ 
is a group homomorphism, $P\otimes P$ can be considered as (acyclic) complex of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules via $D$. By standard homological algebra there is a $\mathbb{Z}G$-linear map $\Delta: P \to P \otimes P$ (called a *diagonal approximation*) that extends $id: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Finally, if $M,N$ are $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules, the *cup product* is defined on cochain level by the morphism

$$\begin{array}{lll}
Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(P,M) \otimes Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(P,N) & \xrightarrow{} & Hom_{\mathbb{Z}(G\times G)}(P\otimes P,M\otimes N) \newline 
 & \xrightarrow{\Delta^\ast} & Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(P,M\otimes N)
\end{array}$$

---

Obviously, the same construction can be made with any group homomorphism $G \to G \times G$ in place of $D$.

**Question 1:** What is the motivation to choose the diagonal $D$ for the definition of the cup product ?

Or, to put it the other way round:

**Question 2:** What "cup product" do be get if we choose one of the group homomorphisms
$$G \to G \times G,\;g \mapsto (g,1) \quad\text{ or }\quad G \to G \times G,\; g \mapsto (1,g)\;\; ? $$

Comment: Answer to 1: Because it always exists. If you use the others than...

Answer to 2: You just get the map $H^*G \otimes H^*G \rightarrow H^*G$ that quotients out one of the factors in the tensor product. 

Comment: "...use others than..." should be "use others then"

Comment: I don't understand what it means that the map I'll get quotients out one of the factors in the tensor product ? 

Comment: Nice observations, TJ. (1) The diagonal map is a gift. It makes any set (any space) into a coalgebra. So any symm. monoidal contravariant functor from sets (spaces) gives you an algebra for every set (space). This is why, morally, cohomology of a space has the structure of an algebra. So when you have a functor like "cochains on a group," it's natural to examine the diagonal, motivated (for me) by this standard fact from topology, to yield an algebraic structure like the cup product.

Comment: @TJ: Sorry, meant to say it quotients out the reduced cohomology of one of the factors. This is what is now explained below in John's answer.

Also, both John and Hiro give much better answers to (1).

Comment: Naturality of the cup product is «a big thing», and that comes straight from the naturality of the diagonal map. I'll bet that there are not a lot of other natural maps into the product!

Comment: It is interesting to note that Cartan and Eilenberg, in the chapter on products of their book, consider cup products induced by arbitrary "diagonal" maps. They have to assume coassociativity to get associativity of the product and so on, of course (there is more leeway, anyways, as one needs *only* a diagonal map on resolutions of $\mathbb Z$, and those can be taken non-coassociative and worse :-) )

Comment: @Mariano: The diagonal map is unique in the following sense.  In any cartesian category (i.e. category with finite products, in which the symmetric monoidal structure is chosen to be categorical product), on any object the diagonal map is the _unique_ comultiplication making that object into a _counital_ coassociative coalgebra. So the answer to @TJ's question is that the other maps do not give a unital cup product, as can be seen explicitly from @John's answer, in which "cup product with $\beta$" is sometimes the zero map.

Comment: @Theo, as you say, the diagonal is the unique comultiplication that turns the group into a counital coassociative coalgebra in the appropriate category —but that is sort of irrelevant here, where what one wants is to turn the *cohomology* of the group into an associative algebra, and one could possibly have the latter without the former! I honestly do not know if, given a group, the diagonal is the unique map from which one can get an associative product in cohomology, but I am pretty sure that it is the only *natural* way to do it (natural in the sense of category theory, of course)

Comment: @Mariano: I think there is an associative product on the cohm. of Thompson's group $F$ that is induced by a non-diagonal hom. $F \times F \to F$: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/papers/homology.pdf (2.2). But I don't know if it has a unit.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal map $\Delta$ is "coassociative": the two maps $(\Delta \otimes 1) \circ \Delta$ and $(1 \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$ from $\mathbb{Z}G$ to $(\mathbb{Z}G)^{\otimes 3}$ are equal. Therefore $\Delta$ induces an *associative* product on cohomology. Similarly, the map $\varepsilon: \mathbb{Z}G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\varepsilon(g)=1$ for all $g \in G$ induces the unit map $\mathbb{Z} \to H^*(G)$ in cohomology for the product induced by $\Delta$, because of how $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$ interact. Other choices for "diagonals" won't do this, in general.

(The fancy thing to say is that $\mathbb{Z}G$ is a *Hopf algebra*, with structure maps given by the usual product and unit, along with $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$, and also a map $\chi: \mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z}G$ defined by $\chi(g) = g^{-1}$ for $g \in G$.)

For question 2, Dylan is saying that the map $g \mapsto (g,1)$ will induce the "product" map $\alpha \otimes \beta \mapsto \alpha \beta$ if $\beta \in H^0(G)$ (i.e. $\beta$ is a scalar), $\alpha \otimes \beta \mapsto 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Actually, the map $g \mapsto (g, 1)$ induces a product which carries $\alpha \otimes \beta$ to $\alpha$ only when $\beta \in H^0(G)$; otherwise the "product" is $0$.

Comment: @Craig Westerland: Oh, you're right. fixed.